# IntelliJ Idea auto create new method

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

In eclipse, I can just move the mouse on a new method name and click to create a new method. I wonder how can I do it with Android studio (which is based on IntelliJ Idea).

Comment: what about ctrl+enter on the new method, it will create it

Comment: Could you tell me what's the name of this shorcut or the shorcut in Mac?

Comment: in linux it is EditorChooseLookupItemAlways, (what a strange name if you ask me :) ) anyways i'm not using Andriod studio, this is plain idea community edition shortcut

Comment: that may helps, but i find the function i want in an icon just besides the method name.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`Ctrl+I` enables you to create default methods for methods you have to `I`mplement.

`Ctrl+O` enables you to create default methods for methods you have to `O`verride.

`Alt+Insert` enables you to generate commons methods (getters, setters, constructors etc...)

If you call a method that does not exist, `Alt+Enter` opens a list of quick fixes. You can then generate a default code for this method.

Comment: For example, I type `initView("he")` in `OnCreate()`,and I wonder how to auto-generate `private void initView(String str){}`

Comment: This method is not one of the default methods or commons methods.

Comment: In this case, IntelliJ shows an error. Try `Alt + Enter`. As a quick fix, IntelliJ will enable you to auto-generate this method (I edited my answer).

Comment: Could you tell me what's the name of this shorcut or the shorcut in Mac?

Comment: i find the it in an icon just besides the method name.

Comment: In Mac, in version 2016.2, the shortcut is Option+Return (for those googling for the answer).

Answer (score 8):

On Mac you can use the following shortcuts

**Option + Return** : Implements all methods that have to be implemented or overridden

**Cmd + I** : Lists all methods that are unimplemented

Answer (score 4):

**Option + Return** while the cursor is over `myMethod()` gives me the option to *create method `myMethod()`*.

Comment: How do you do this for all the methods missing in a class?